# Can I invest using the All Weather Portfolio strategy buying US stocks but on the London Stock Exchange?

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, etf, stock-markets, investment-strategies

I really like Ray Dalio’s ‘All Weather Portfolio strategy’ and I would like to follow this, but I’m struggling to find relatable USA ETF’s that I can buy into on the LSE.

Even if I did manage to find ETF’s that would work for this, does it make sense financially to buy into them? - i.e tax and converting Dollars to GBP

Answer (score 1):

There's VUSA.L and VUSD.L. They are Vanguard's S&P500 ETF in GBP and USD, respectively.

I'm not an expert in UK taxes, but since they are traded on the LSE, I'd imagine they would get taxed similarly to any other stock there.